# Pandas disassemble column

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, split

From the documentaiton of pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html a assembly of multiple columns e.g. date columns to a single one is explained.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                        'month': [2, 3],
                        'day': [4, 5]})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df) 
0   2015-02-04 1   2016-03-05 dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But how can I perform the opposite transformation?

Comment: Sorry what is the desired output? You want to split the datetime back to it's constituent parts? you can do `df['year'],df['month'],df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month, df['Date'].dt.day`

Comment: Thanks. This is the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dt.strftime('%Y %-m %-d').str.split()` will reverse the operation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                        'month': [2, 3],
                        'day': [4, 5]})
pd.to_datetime(df)

0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
pd.to_datetime(df).dt.strftime('%Y %-m %-d').str.split()

0    [2015, 2, 4]
1    [2016, 3, 5]
dtype: object
```

---

Or with a fancy regex extract

```
regex = r'(?P<year>\d+) (?P<month>\d+) (?P<day>\d+)'
pd.to_datetime(df).dt.strftime('%Y %-m %-d') \
    .str.extract(regex, expand=True).astype(int)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can access the constituent parts of a datetime using the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor, note that `to_datetime` returns a `Series` so I'm converting to a df in order to add columns:

```
In [71]:
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df)
df1 = df1.to_frame()
df1 = df1.rename(columns={0:'date'})
df1

Out[71]:
        date
0 2015-02-04
1 2016-03-05

In [72]:
df1['year'], df1['month'], df1['day'] = df1['date'].dt.year, df1['date'].dt.month, df1['date'].dt.day
df1

Out[72]:
        date  year  month  day
0 2015-02-04  2015      2    4
1 2016-03-05  2016      3    5
```

the dtypes will be `int64` for each component:

```
In [73]:    
df1.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
date     2 non-null datetime64[ns]
year     2 non-null int64
month    2 non-null int64
day      2 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(3)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the components via `df1.date.apply(operator.attrgetter('year', 'month', 'day'))`

Comment: @JonClements that would be more succinct but I always advise against `apply` when a vectorised solution exists, although I do find it puzzling why some `.str` and `.dt` operations appear to be slower than `apply` or `map` sometimes, also that would return a tuple so you'd need to access each element